# SQL Azure "database 'x' on server 'y' is not currently available." for HOURS -- anybody else experiencing this?

Tags: sql, azure

I'm using Azure SQL and everything was working fine until around 2PM CT today when all my cloud instances started giving me this error:

> EXCEPTION: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Database 'x' on server 'y' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of 'z'

**Has anyone else been experiencing this?** I made no code changes between the time when it was working and 2PM. I thought it might be Microsoft adding some additional IP addresses to their cloud environment and forgetting (again) to add it to the firewall exclusion list for Azure SQL, but I checked that and manually added, no difference. I also tested from my local workstation test environment as well which was working fine this morning, which definitely has the firewall rules in place, and that's not working either.

The really, really strange this is that I can connect into the SQL Azure Manage portal just fine, and I can also connect from Visual Studio directly in (as I always have been able) and issue queries to the same database that's reporting errors above.

**Did Microsoft change something today on their side rendering any features obsolete?** The database I'm trying to access *is* a Federation master for two other databases, and I know that they announced that they are getting rid of that, but I wouldn't think that would have anything to do with it.

**Can someone recommend how I might go about troubleshooting such a condition to identify the root cause?** I'm scratching my head on this one and my cloud services are down.

*** UPDATE ***

OK I've been able to track this down further. This is 100% a Federations issue.

Earlier today I could connect to my Federation master and issue a normal `USE FEDERATION` command. Now, however, this doesn't work. I get the error I described above and a login error. So, apparently something Microsoft did today completely screwed us Federation customers over. Again.

If anybody knows how to fix this on our own, please let me know. If I find a solution, I'll post likewise.

Comment: "If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of 'z'"

Comment: Mitch, not everyone (including myself) can afford those Microsoft support contracts. Hence why I'm posting it here, where Microsoft recommends as per the verbiage on their support portal.

Comment: Hi, have you find the solution?